# Расшифровка WPA2 на нескольких ПК без словаря

Tags: взлом, брутфорс

Добрый день) Друзья если кто знает подскажите пожалуйста.

Имеется файл (хендшейк) с WPA2 шифрованием.

Известна длина пароля: 8 символов
Известны символы которые входят в пароль: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789

Допустим имеется железо: AMD fx-8120 и radeon rx550 что позволит перебрать такой пароль примерно за 2 года!

Допустим имеется 24 таких машин, т. е. если каждая из них возьмёт на себя часть задачи, то пароль найдётся за 1 месяц.
Используемое ПО hashcat (не важно графическая или нет, и не важно какая ОС)

Вопрос: Как распределить эту задачу на N-количество машин?

Comment: Ну, пусть первая машина перебирает пароли, начинающиеся с `AA` до `BP`, вторая - от `BQ до С9`, и т.д.

Comment: Это гениально, я тоже об этом думал. Но всёже может есть какая то функция у hashcat. Прост в программу можно прервать, а затем она может продолжать перебирать пароль уже на другом ПК. Но я не нашел где информация о том, что программа уже перебрала.